# Issues in RSA setup

Tags: cryptography, encryption, modular-arithmetic

Suppose we have public key: $$n= 1015, e= 3$$ and private key: $$d=  635, p=  35, q=  29, \phi(n)=  952$$
For $m = 100$, we have $$c = m^e ~mod~n = 100^3 mod~1015 = 225.$$
To decipher this, let us take $$c^d~mod~n$$ which is $$225^{635}~mod~1015$$ which equals $$680$$ But $680 \neq 100$ so this means that RSA incorrectly decrypted it right? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your public key is not a legal RSA public key.  In RSA, $n$ must be a product of two primes, but 35 is not a prime.  Therefore, things don't work right: for instance, you got the wrong value of $\phi(n)$.

Comment: [RSA works](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1006/991) even when the "message $m$ is not relatively prime to the modulus $n$". $\:$ The real problem is that, since $p$ is not prime, he got a wrong value of $\phi(n)$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer, oh, right, good point!  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @D.W. My implementation of isPrime(n) was slightly wrong...it went up to √n , when I adjusted it to go up to (√n) + 1 it works correctly.